# Does SSAS Tabular have support for aggregated tables?

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular

Power BI has introduced support for aggregated tables.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-aggregations

Does SSAS Tabular have this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment SSAS Tabular & Azure Analysis Services doesn't support the Aggregation Feature, that is in Power BI Desktop and the service